# Public array to shuffle values between subroutines?

Tags: vba

How do I get a public array whose values are set within a subroutine and do not get cleared at the end of the sub in which they were set?

I tried to get:

```
Public GlobalArray() as Variant

Sub One()
    ReDim GlobalArray(0 to 2)
    GlobalArray=Array("0","1","2")
End Sub

Sub Two()
    Check = GlobalArray(2)
End Sub
```

such that Check = 2, but I get thrown an error in sub Two complaining about a lack of values in GlobalArray (in fact, even sub One complains that there is no GlobalArray to put things in).

Basically, I have a procedure (One) pulling data from disparate sources, doing some stuff with it, letting the user do some things in Excel, and then running a new subroutine (Two) that uses both the user's input and some of the arrays from sub One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Public GlobalArray() variable must be declared in a module.  It will not work if it is declared at the top of either a Worksheet or the ThisWorkbook module. Try:

```
'// Must be declared in a module    
Public GlobalArray() As Integer

'// These routines can be in worksheet/thisworkbook modules along side events etc Or in a module
Sub One()
    ReDim GlobalArray(0 To 2)
    GlobalArray(0) = 0
    GlobalArray(1) = 1
    GlobalArray(2) = 2
End Sub

Sub Two()
    check = GlobalArray(2)
    MsgBox (check)
End Sub
```

Instead of a public variable you could pass it to the second function:

```
Sub One()

    Dim GlobalArray(0 To 2) As Integer
    GlobalArray(0) = 0
    GlobalArray(1) = 1
    GlobalArray(2) = 2

    Two GlobalArrayToMe:=GlobalArray
End Sub

Sub Two(ByRef GlobalArrayToMe() As Integer)

    check = GlobalArrayToMe(2)
    MsgBox (check)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure VBA passes all arrays ByRef but just in case... On the second half you might want to include Sub Two(ByRef GlobalArrayToMe() as Integer) or variant, or whatever type of array it is. This way you don't eat up huge chunks of memory. Which VBA/Excel loves to do.

Comment: Actually, VBA passes arrays by value, so you do need the ByRef if you want to avoid copying the array when passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not VBA and won't compile: `GlobalArray=("0","1","2")`

You could instead use: `GlobalArray = Array("0", "1", "2")`

but that requires declaring `Public GlobalArray() As Variant`

Otherwise assign the array elements one by one as in @Readfidy's answer.

Comment: Thanks - clarified the question.