# Declare array input argument

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having a lot of trouble with just using an Array of known length as an input argument to a VBA sub/function. I've tried a couple of the fixes/workarounds in other answers, but for some reason or another none of them work.

I still can't get it to work, here's an example of my actual code:

```
Sub toDo()

ReDim thisArray(1 To 4, 1 To 10): k = 1
For i = 1 To 4
For j = 1 To 10
thisArray(i, j) = k
k = k + 1
Next: Next

pasteArray(Ubound(thisArray,1), Ubound(thisArray,2),2,2,thisArray)

End Sub

Public Sub pasteArray(x As Integer, y As Integer, _
locX As Integer, locY As Integer, _
ParamArray myArray() As Variant)

ReDim myArray(1 To x, 1 To y) As Double
Range(Cells(locX, locY), Cells(x + locX - 1, y + locY - 1)) = myArray

End Sub
```

I just want to past thisArray() to cell(2,2), but I now get a Compile Error: Syntax Error, on the line in my toDo Sub that calls the pasteArray sub.

I also get a Compile Error: Expecting = , on that same line. And I have no clue why as it shouldn't be returning anything.

Comment: We need some more information - what are you trying to do with `useArray`? Or are you generally asking how do you use the array (`someArray`) from the `mainToDo()` sub in the `useArray` sub?

Comment: I have modified the submitted code a little and I've included an example sub I've been trying to implement. I've been getting my code to work by just  not making a sub so far. However, since I'll be doing this fairly commonly I'd like to abandon this workaround and have it packaged in a nice sub. =D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Sub mainToDo()
    Dim someArray(1 To 10) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
'    For Each ind In someArray
'        ind = i
'        i = i + 1
'    Next
    For j = 1 To 10
        someArray(j) = i
        i = i + 1
    Next

    useArray (someArray)

End Sub

Sub useArray(arr As Variant)
    For i = LBound(someArray) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

I've commented your `For...Loop` because it was not storing the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mainToDo()
Dim someArray(1 To 10) As Integer
Dim ind
  ' Dim someArray(1 To 10)
    Dim i As Integer: i = 1
    For Each ind In someArray
        ind = i
        i = i + 1
    Next
    useArray someArray
End Sub
```

Then just set up the second sub. like this:

```
Sub useArray(ByRef someArray() As Integer)
Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
    Debug.Print someArray(i)
    ' Do whatever you want here, with each array item.
Next i
End Sub
```

Note: Your current `mainToDo()` isn't setting any values into the `someArray`, so the second sub will just print `0` for each item in the array.

Also, you could pass the array as a global variable, and use it as such (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693402/public-array-to-shuffle-values-between-subroutines) for example).